# where to find Native Ruby source code such as instance_exec?

Tags: ruby, implementation, definition

i know that there is the function "method(:instance_exec).source_location" to look for source code, but only works for code in gems. But it returns null in this particular case since the method is from native ruby. i am googling but i am not able to find where this is written.
in my particular case, i want to have a better idea of how instance_exec changes the values of the scope of a proc

going on a tangent, im looking to do this for college

```
precondition { divisor != 0 } 
postcondition { |result| result * divisor == dividend}
  def divide(dividend, divisor)
    dividend / divisor
  end
```

i know instance_exec changes 'self' value in the proc scope. i want to add 'divisor' to the scope of `{ divisor != 0 }` proc when i run it, and i think that reading the implementation of instance_exec would be very helpfull.
Since it is for college, i cant use any gem to do this, only standard ruby

PS right_click + Go To + Implementation only shows me

```
  def instance_exec(*args)
    # This is a stub implementation, used for type inference (actual method behavior may differ)
    yield
  end
```

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec

Comment: thanks, but the link provided explains how to use the method. Im looking for what it does under the hood, the source code of it. Thats what i meant for 'its implemantation', not how to use it. i aim to extend it in a way so i can pass not only the arguments of the block, but also set the variables of it's scope

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_1/vm_eval.c#L2003-L2033 – not sure how the C code is going to help though.

Comment: To have a method `divisor` within the block, you have to add it to the object `self` is referring to, i.e. the receiver of `instance_exec`

Answer (score 0):

> i know that there is the function "method(:instance_exec).source_location" to look for source code, but only works for code in gems.

That's not true. `Method#source_location` works just fine for methods which are not in gems:

```rb
module Foo
  def bar; end
end

p Foo.instance_method(:bar).source_location
#=> ['test.rb', 2]
```

There is no gem here. In fact, it even works if I don't use any file at all, just by using `ruby -e` on the command line; the result will be `['-e', 2]` in that case.

On the other hand, if there *is no Ruby source*, then it will return `nil` *even for gems*.

The return value of `Method#source_location` has nothing to do with whether or not the method is from a gem, the only thing that matters is whether there even *is* a Ruby source to locate.

> But it returns null in this particular case since the method is from native ruby.

It shouldn't return `null`, it should return either a two-element array or `nil`, but never `null`. There seems to be something seriously broken with your Ruby installation if that is really the case.

> i am googling but i am not able to find where this is written.

It will be somewhere in the source code of the Ruby implementation you are using. You haven't specified which implementation you are using, so I cannot tell you exactly, but here are some examples:

In [Rubinius](http://rubinius.com/), it is implemented in [`core/basic_object.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/basic_object.rb#L146-L161):

> ```rb
> def instance_exec(*args, &prc)
>   raise ::LocalJumpError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
>   env = prc.block
>
>   return prc.ruby_method.call(*args) if prc.ruby_method
>
>   lexical_scope = env.lexical_scope
>   if ::ImmediateValue === self
>     lexical_scope = lexical_scope.using_disabled_scope
>   else
>     sc = ::Rubinius::Type.object_singleton_class(self)
>     lexical_scope = lexical_scope.using_current_as(sc)
>   end
>
>
>   return env.call_under(self, lexical_scope, true, *args)
> end
> ```

In [TruffleRuby](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby), it is implemented in [`src/main/java/org/truffleruby/core/basicobject/BasicObjectNodes.java`](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/java/org/truffleruby/core/basicobject/BasicObjectNodes.java#L429-L455):

> ```java
> @CoreMethod(names = "instance_exec", needsBlock = true, rest = true)
> public abstract static class InstanceExecNode extends CoreMethodArrayArgumentsNode {
>
>     public static InstanceExecNode create() {
>         return InstanceExecNodeFactory.create(null);
>     }
>
>     @Child private CallBlockNode callBlockNode = CallBlockNode.create();
>
>     abstract Object executeInstanceExec(Object self, Object[] args, RubyProc block);
>
>     @Specialization
>     protected Object instanceExec(Object receiver, Object[] arguments, RubyProc block) {
>         final DeclarationContext declarationContext = new DeclarationContext(
>                 Visibility.PUBLIC,
>                 new SingletonClassOfSelfDefaultDefinee(receiver),
>                 block.declarationContext.getRefinements());
>         return callBlockNode
>                 .executeCallBlock(declarationContext, block, receiver, block.block, arguments);
>     }
>
>     @Specialization
>     protected Object instanceExec(Object receiver, Object[] arguments, NotProvided block) {
>         throw new RaiseException(getContext(), coreExceptions().localJumpError("no block given", this));
>     }
>
> }
> ```